# Fetch row by various key strings SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I had a db with columns named as `product id,name,price`etc.. Now i need to fetch the row by giving string like `"123 cooldrink 94"`. Then it fetches the rows where the column contains these string as their values. For these 123 may be either `product id/price`. But need to fetch row where these strings matches with column.

```
product id  price  productname
123          94     Snacks
145          123    Cooldrink
```

If i give input the text as "123 94" then it brings 1st as result. May be user type "94 123" also displays the same result.

Comment: So, it's MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL or what?

Comment: if you provide some sample data with expected output, it will be very useful to give answer

Comment: The question was what RDBMS are you using? There is no RDBMS with a name SQL.

Comment: i use sqlite for android

Comment: I think Full Text search is what you are looking for.
http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Comment: @Shalini - got solution???

Comment: @Shalini - whats the problem with peterm's second answer?

Comment: the search box has values to search for product name, price, id,etc..

Comment: are you saying depending upon the number of search items you need to modify query ? i cant see any problem in second answer of peterm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** A possible solution might be to split your string on the client by space and then use a query like this (if you need exact matches in columns)

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM products
 WHERE product_id IN (123, 94)
    OR price IN (123, 94)
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM products
 WHERE 93  IN (product_id, price, productname)
    OR 123 IN (product_id, price, productname)
    OR 'cooldrink' IN (product_id, price, productname)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/216e2/4)** demo

Now if you need to ensure that both of the keywords are either price or product_id for the same row

```
SELECT * 
  FROM products
 WHERE (product_id = 123 AND price =  94)
    OR (product_id = 94 AND price =  123)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6108c/2)** demo

Another way, if partial matches are OK, to approach this

```
SELECT product_id, price, productname
  FROM
(
  SELECT p.*, ',' || product_id || ',' || price || ',' || productname || ',' details
  FROM products p
)
WHERE details LIKE ',%94%,' 
   OR details LIKE ',%123%,'
   OR details LIKE ',%cool%,'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6108c/11)** demo

Comment: it might be long when i use product name, other columns as input while fetching

Comment: Yes it might and you have to specify all the columns you want to search in and all the possible values (search keywords) anyway. There is no silver bullet for that in standard SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got solution,

```
 (productname like '%value1%' or productname like '%value2%')AND
 (productnumberone like '%value1%'or productnumberone like
 '%value2%')AND (price like '%value1%'or price like '%value2%')
```